# Understanding p-value and its relation with the value $\alpha$ used in tests

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I am having a little trouble understanding these concepts. Let’s take a real problem, for instance. I buy some machinery, and I know newer models break down with an exponential probability of mean 5 years, and the old ones have the same kind of probability distribution but the mean for them breaking down is 3 years.

Let’s suppose the machines are of the newer type. It can be seen (rigorously and also intuitively) that given $n$ machines that break down in a time $X_i$, the critical region to look at is something like $\{ \sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i < d\}$. Then let’s say I take a level $\alpha$, that is I want $P(\{ \sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i < d\})< \alpha$. It can be shown that the sum has a distribution $\chi ^2$. The question is, given a value for $n$,$\alpha$ and the sum, if the value of $\alpha$ is little, then the corresponding quantil (value of $d$) will also be little and the value of the sum is more likely to not fall on the critical region, thus making the null hypothesis more likely to be accepted.

What I don’t get is how this is possible. The value of $\alpha$ should represent the risk that if the hypothesis is true, the variable falls in the critical region. How come that I can reject the hypothesis for a value of $\alpha$ and accept it for a smaller one? Shouldn’t littler values of $\alpha$ indicate more precision and thus be more difficult to attain?

Comment: The hypothesis you seem to test is "New machines last at least as long as the old ones". At least that is what i read from $P(\sum_iX_i < d) < \alpha$. The value of $\alpha$, as you said, represents the risk of reject the hypothesis, allthough it's true. So shrinking $\alpha$ will also shrink the corresponding $d$, thus it's harder to reject your hypothesis, i.e. new machines will be accepted as as durable as the old ones more probably. I see no contradiction, tbh..

Comment: @denklo I am testing the hypothesis “The machines last 5 years” vs “The machines last 3 years”. What I don’t get is this: you refuse, say, $\alpha=0.05$. That is, you have 5% probability to refuse the hypothesis even if it is true. What does this rejection mean? And why do I accept it if $\alpha$ is, for example, 0.025? I mean, in the first case I fall on the critical region and that (if the hypothesis is true) happens 5% of the time. But then if I take a littler $\alpha$ I accept the hypothesis and attain a stronger result (only 2.5% of the times I refuse a true hypothesis).

Comment: The rejection means that you can safely state "We reject the hypothesis according to our condition $\sum X_i < d$. The probability of us doing so by chance, allthough the hypotheses is valid, is $\alpha$". I.e. the more you limit alpha, the harder the hypothesis is to reject. If you reduce $\alpha$, then of course it is harder to reject the hypothesis. Usually the test are designed in testing the statement A versus !A, i.e. in you case it should be "The machines last more than 5 years" vs. "The machines last NOT more than 5 years, i.e. less than 5 years". Maybe thats the problem?